# ORMLite not update with the same count of object

Tags: android, ormlite

I try to make simple test. I have json response from REST API with ~250 objects shops and the same response in file but first shop has different name. First step is load JSON file with ~250 shops and save in local db using ORMLite. Next step is connect with API and get the same response. New json response is parse and UPDATE exist elements in database. What is result?

Now I go to simple Activity with ListView and call `getShopsAll()`. This method return old data before update. Why?
This is method to save shop in database:

```
public void createShop(final ArrayList<ModelSklep> list) throws Exception {
    getDaoShop().callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {      
        @Override
        public Void call() {
            for(ModelSklep item : list) {
                createShop(item);
                if(item.getHoursList().size() > 0) {
                    createHours(item.getHoursList());
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Method createshop:

```
public boolean createShop(ModelSklep item) {
    try {
        getDaoShop().createOrUpdate(item);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Method getShopAll:

```
public ArrayList<ModelSklep> getShopAll() {
    try {
        return (ArrayList<ModelSklep>) getDaoShop().queryBuilder().orderByRaw(
                "nazwaPelna COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC").query();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Object is updating. But getShopAll() return old data object.
Clear cache after update doesn't work.

Help. I don't know how resolve this problem.

**[Edit]**

```
public Dao<ModelSklep, Integer> getDaoShop() {
    if(modelShopDao == null) {
        try {
            modelShopDao = getDao(ModelSklep.class);
            modelShopDao.setObjectCache(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return modelShopDao;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your `getShopAll()` method?

Comment: I add getShopAll i post

Comment: Are you sure no exceptions are being thrown? At first glance this looks like it should be fine

Comment: Yes, I check exception with breakpoints and nothing to do

Comment: OK, can we also see the getDaoShop method too?

Comment: I think about cache. Clear cache after create shops item don't get result

Comment: I believe if you remove the setting of the cache, it should work as expected

Comment: Solution: drop down table and create new list elements